# Is it possible to hold a mysql object across sessions in php?

Tags: php, mysql, session

For example, in this case, the 'views' count is clearly incrementing properly during the session but the mysqli object is not maintained and cannot be reused during the session (if the page is refreshed or whatever).  Can the _SESSION global only hold simple types? What else could be limiting this?  EDIT: my hope here is to improve performance.  So if there is another way to achieve this, I'd be happy to know.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['db']))
{
    $mysqli = $_SESSION['db'];
    $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
}
else
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli(...);
    $_SESSION['db'] = $mysqli;
    $_SESSION['views']=1;
}

echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];    

?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` only holds simple types and serialized data.  While it can hold an object, it cannot hold an object's state or values.  When the page is refreshed, the `$_SESSION` values are also refreshed, meaning a new instance of objects.

Comment: Why do you need that? What real issue is behind this attempt?

Comment: @zerkms - my hope was to improve performance by not re-creating the connection.  If there is a way to do that, please let me know.

Comment: @glutz: why do you think you need to improve performance by doing that? Have you profiled your application and found that this is the slowest part in your code?

Answer (score 3):

Nope, none of php resources is serializable. So you need to instantiate `mysqli` object each time.

> EDIT: my hope here is to improve performance.

The number one performance optimization rule is: first measure - second optimize. No one in the world can say what's the performance issue without profiling (measuring).

So, your application works unacceptable slow? Well, measure what makes it so slow and optimize that particular place. And I can assure you it's not the connection to mysql.

Comment: well, i kind of just assumed. but i will profile it.  im pretty surprised to hear that the db connection is not a bottleneck. thanks.

Comment: @glutz: the bottleneck usually is db queries, but, as I said, you need to measure before you start optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly. But you could use magic methods: [`__sleep()` and `__wakeup()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.wakeup).

```
class Connection {
    protected $link;
    private $server, $username, $password, $db;

    public function __construct($server, $username, $password, $db) {
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect() {
        $this->link = mysql_connect($this->server, $this->username, $this->password);
        mysql_select_db($this->db, $this->link);
    }

    public function __sleep() {
        return array('server', 'username', 'password', 'db');
    }

    public function __wakeup() {
        $this->connect();
    }
}
```

I don't think it's necessary doing so in with the session.